# Angular navigation from database

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I'm new to learning how to do things in Angular5 and am having a difficult time wrapping my head around creating a dynamic menu for my app. The navigation consists of three different parts

1. Menu Groups - A group that contains any number of navigation items. These items can either point to a component or a sub-menu that contains navigation items.
2. Menu Cards - Individual cards that contain an ID, a name, a navigation target (name of a component or another menu card that will point to a component or another menu)
3. MenuCardGroups - A bridge table that specifies what cards belong to what group and what order they should be sorted

I don't have any control over how the database is structured so whatever solution I devise has to conform to that.

I have created a menu service that can get data from the database and I have a menu component that currently works with a hard coded router file. However, I cannot find any examples of tying these things together. For example, when someone first logs in, they will get the top level navigation. I find that by getting a list of all items in the Menu Groups table that don't specify they have a parent item. In my case, this could be a Time Management group that would cause the menu to reload displaying cards for Time Entry, Request Time Off, View PTO Balance, etc. Each of those cards could point to a component that the user can work with or another menu to choose tasks from.

Different users will have different menu structures available to them as defined by their permissions in the database, this is why I can't hard code any routes into the app as I don't know what will or won't be used for any particular user.

What tools/techniques/patterns do I need to research to move forward with this task? What is the "appropriate" way to go to a database in Angular, pass it a querystring parameter and get back a result set that is then rendered into content dynamically? Before I write more code, I really do want to make sure I fully understand the steps involved to create the routes dynamically at run time.

Comment: You can set up the routes that your app has and use route guards to restrict user access to those routes if a user isn't supposed to have access to them (e.g. the user manually altered the url to try to get to a route they aren't supposed to get to). It is then up to your code to use your service to construct your menu from your end point that will show the user the routes they have access to. Did you walk through the Angular tutoarial on Routing & Navigation? They discuss how to do this there: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I have gone through that. That's how I was able to create a "proof of concept" by manually configuring some routes and making sure they worked. However, I literally do not know what routes will or won't be available for any given user. They may have 5 items available, or 10, or 15. Route guards will definitely be a part of the solution but I don't know what will or won't be available to manually code it.

Comment: How does the service work to figure out the routes available to the user? Are they related to security rights that the user has?

Comment: We will use a SQL join to tie the user's ID to a table where an administrator has identified what items their users will have available to them. The end result is I can pass in a querystring with a user ID and other properties and get back a list of the components a user has available to them at whatever level they are currently at.

Comment: You probably want to look into having your Angular service that loads the routes cache the result of the components a user has access to and have your route guard use that to verify that the user has access to the component